# I'm trying to stream data from alpaca API. Using json.dumps gives me error code: Object of type set is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, websocket, simplejson

[Image of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueQQ3.jpg)

> Tried json.stringify

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I just wanted to let you know that a screenshot of the code is not the best for both searchability of your question for others who might encounter the same problem, and is also much less likely to get an answer.

Comment: Please edit your post so that it doesn't contain an [image of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in this line:

```py
auth_message = {"action": "auth", "key": {api_key}, "secret": {secret_key}}
```

In Python, `{something}` is the syntax to create a set, which can also have multiple items: `{1, 2, 3}` is the set that contains only 1, 2 and 3. ([here's the documentation for sets in Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)).

What you probably *actually* want is to just reference the values directly, so

```py
auth_message = {"action": "auth", "key": api_key, "secret": secret_key}
```

I assume the confusion might've come from the fact that curly braces *are* used to get something into a format string of the form `f"here curly braces do do what you probably thought they'd do here: {3 * 4}"` (this would be equal to `"here curly braces do do what you probably thought they'd do here: it 12"`) or `"the older way with .format also exists {}".format(3)` (would be `"the older way with .format also exists 3"`) - but this is only the case in [string interpolations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).